# Distinct limits for To and CC recipients vs BCC recipients in Outlook on Office 365?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I would like to enforce two limits in Outlook on Office 365

- the maximum number of `To` plus `CC` recipients
- the maximum number of `BCC` recipients

Indeed, while it's (sometimes) OK-ish to send an email to dozens of recipients, doing it in CC is asking for trouble as somebody *will be replying* with *reply to all*.

Thus, I would like to enforce a limit at 10 for all visible recipients `To` plus `CC`, while keeping a limit at, say, 100 for `BCC`.

How can I do this?

Comment: This likely would have to be a custom extension that you write that detects the number of recipients. How you write a. outlook extension, however, wouldn’t be within scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into this as well. Unfortunately there appears to be no option to set separate limits for To/CC and BCC. This is also confirmed in [this article on the Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/limit-number-of-addresses-in-to-and-cc-field-but/a6675286-74e0-4e62-8b74-e3674bd9854d).

I did find a third party plugin that allows you to set separate limits. Unfortunately it's quite pricy for a single feature plugin. More info here:
https://ivasoft.com/restrictextrecipsowa.shtml

If you find a better option, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Set-Mailbox` cmdlet.

The `RecipientLimits` parameter specifies the maximum number of recipients allowed in messages sent by the mailbox. There are currently no To/CC/BCC specific values.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, currently there aren't any built-in features to achieve this.
In O365 Exchange Online recipients limits are standard and its apply to all field (TO, CC and BCC) , we cannot restrict recipients limits.

Here is an official article for your reference:[Exchange Online Limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#receiving-and-sending-limits)

So I think you may need look for some third-party add-ins for Outlook.